How do I ensure that MySQL is writing out its error log as the correct user?
I have a development Airflow server. It uses MySQL as its database. In the mysqld settings, I have the user set to mysql.
However, the log is being written out as a different user named adm whenever the log is rolled over. I have confirmed I have set the desired user to mysql in the config, restarted the MySQL service to pick up this change, but it is still changing daily to adm. How can I make it so that the mysql user writes out the error log file after rolling over?
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
...
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

Sample current directory:
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql  4096 Oct 23 13:37 .
drwxrwxr-x 13 root  syslog 4096 Oct 23 00:00 ..
-rw-r-----  1 adm   adm     0   Oct 23 00:00 error.log

Desired directory:
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql  4096 Oct 23 13:37 .
drwxrwxr-x 13 root  syslog 4096 Oct 23 00:00 ..
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql   0   Oct 23 00:00 error.log


You probably need to fix this in the configuration of the log rolling script, not mysql.

Barmar posted this as comment and solved it - it is indeed the log rotate configuration at /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server.
The previous config line was create 640 mysql adm. I changed it to create 640 mysql mysql.
